# content attribute text color - css

Tags: css, pseudo-element, css-content

I would like to add color to a text in the content attribute. I did like this, didn't work

```
 .atleastTwoChars:after
 {
    content: "2*";
    float: left;
    width: 16px;
    height: 14px;
    border: 0;
    margin: 2px 3px 0px 3px;
    color:#FFBC0000;
}
```

Comment: At least, this should be: `color: #FFBC00;`. Note the number of alphanumeric characters (6).

Comment: This is not possible because there is no tag and every style definition should be related to a tag.

Comment: @micha: What are you talking about?

Comment: @micha - `:after` is an element. See mesiesta's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 8 digits in your color:

```
color:#FFBC0000;
```

Were your extra two zeroes added by accident?

```
color:#FFBC00;
```

Or does the `FF` represent 100% alpha (completely opaque)? If so, leave it out; CSS hex colors don't support specifying the alpha channel, only the `rgba()` notation does:

```
color:#BC0000;
```

Comment: A answer shouldn't be a question...?

Comment: OK, I made it a little less interrogative.